# Check programmatically if encoding is supported

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Is there a way to find out if an encoding is supported or not? E. g. a method like this:

```
isSupported("UTF-8") == true
```

and

```
isSupported("UTF-13") == false
```

I need this to validate if the Content-Disposition-Header of my MimeMessages is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boolean isCharsetSupported(String name) {
  try {
    Charset.forName(name);
    return true;
  } catch (UnsupportedCharsetException | IllegalCharsetNameException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

or without a `try/catch` block:

```
boolean isCharsetSupported(String name) {
    return Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().contains(name);
}
```

Comment: I've hoped for something without exceptions, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Using `Exception`s as flow control is discouraged in Java.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
Charset.isSupported("UTF-8")
```

this method may throw `RuntimeException`s when name is `null` or the name is invalid.

Comment: +1, How could I have overlooked that in Javadoc... Still, it could throw a `IllegalCharsetNameException` if the given charset name is illegal

Comment: @jlordo As I wrote it can throw a `RuntimeException` when the name is invalid.

Comment: The typo I fixed in your answer (of/or) confused me..., sorry.